# Ionic: ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Tags: javascript, android, ios, ionic-framework

I'm getting the error ReferenceError: $ is not defined on my ionic application.

I'm trying to open links in the systems browser from my json file.

Here's the code:

```
  $timeout(function () {
   $('.ex-link').click(function () {
     var url = $(this).attr('href');
     window.open(encodeURI(url), '_system', 'location=yes');
     return false;
   })
})
```

Line which gets the error is:

```
$('.ex-link').click(function () {
```

Comment: jQuery included?? Angular will use jqLite. However you can include jQuery.js before Angular.js and make Angular replace jqLite by jQuery. `$` will be difined.

Comment: So in my index.html i need to add jquery?

Comment: yeas and before including AngularJS

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Angular will use jqLite. However you can include jQuery.js before Angular.js and make Angular replace jqLite by jQuery. $ will be difined.

Include jQuery before including AngularJS as,

```
<!-- Add jQuery from -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>

<!-- And then AngularJS -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="angularjs.js"></script>
```