# I am trying to pass value to the server in ionic using http but i am getting an error

Tags: ionic-framework

see the bellow sample code which i am trying to send it to the server

```
  var serializedData = $.param({
                    api: key,
                    user: $scope.user.username

                });
```

$http({
                        method: 'POST',
                        url: URL+"login_master/login",
                        data: serializedData,
                        headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                    }})....

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: $ is not defined near $.param - same method working fine in cordova but not in ionic

Comment: Then your issue could be a duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31452940/ionic-referenceerror-is-not-defined